# Excel - If cell one is empty, then cell two should be 0

Tags: excel, if-statement

How can I make an if statement, that works this way.

If C1 is not filled, then N41 should be 0, if C1 is filled then N41 should be =AA5.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),0,AA5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple .

Macro

```
if range("C1").value = "" then
range("N41").value =0
else
range("N41").value= range("AA5").value
end if
```

formula

```
=IF(C1="",0,AA5)
```